# "testng doesn't support the nested "java" element."- while executing build.xml - JAR target

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng, executable-jar, build.xml

We wanted to create Jar, deploy and execute the jar file from the remote machine.

As the provision from the testNG created main class file

When running from this class file its perfectly executing, but when are executing form build XML getting the following error

> "testng doesn't support the nested "java" element."
>
> 1. TestNG version - 6.13.1 (tried with lower versions too)
> 2. Eclipse - Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
> 3. Selenium - 3.7.1
> 4. Ant  - 1.10.1

After searching for long time and with different possibilities, i am not able to get the solution for this.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create object of TestNG Class
    TestNG runner = new TestNG();

    // Create a list of String
    List<String> suitefiles = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Add xml file which you have to execute
    suitefiles.add("D:\\Projects\\TestAutomation\\AgainFinal_Jartest\\TestNG.xml");

    // now set xml file for execution
    runner.setTestSuites(suitefiles);

    // finally execute the runner using run method
    runner.run();
}
```

```xml
<!-- compile -->
<target name="compile" depends="init, clean" > 
    <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>
    <echo message="making directory..."/>
    <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
    <echo message="classpath------: ${test.classpath}"/>
    <echo message="compiling..."/>
    <javac debug="true" destdir="${test.dest}" srcdir="${test.src}" target="1.8" classpath="${test.classpath}" includeantruntime="false">
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="JarCreation" depends="compile" description="package, output to JAR">
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
    <echo message="Creating Jarfile ..!"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the {$ws.project.name}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${jar.dir}/${ws.project.name}.jar" basedir="${basedir}" >
        <manifest>
        <!-- create an executable Jar -->
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyWorld.MainTestNGClass"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="build"/>    

    </jar>
    <echo message="Created an executable Jarfile ..!"/> 
</target> 

<!-- build -->
<target name="build" depends="init">
</target>

<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="MyWorld.MainTestNGClass" fork="true"></java>
    <sysproperty key="env.key" value="CK_AUTO_DEV"></sysproperty>
</target>

<target name="runs" depends="compile,JarCreation">
    <testng classpath="./libs/testng-6.13.1.jar" suitename="Framework for Desktop website">         
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ws.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
        <sysproperty key="env.key" value="CK_AUTO_DEV"></sysproperty>
    </testng>
</target>
```

Comment: are you able to create jar file via main class ??

Comment: Yeah , Siddhesh - Able to create

Comment: So is there any special thing that you are trying to achieve using this build xml ?

Comment: Expecting general things only , like executing for multiple targets and create Jar, deploy and execute the jar file from the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is due to the inclusion of `<java jar="${jar.dir}/${ws.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>` in your `<target name="runs" depends="compile,JarCreation">`

To fix this you need to remove the `<java>` element from the `<testng>` element and try again.

For more information on the available options, refer [here](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html)

Comment: Thank you Krishnan , Go the solution based on your direction . Apologies for  delay response.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Runs the file and generates Reportng report for TestNG-->
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${dependencies}/testng-6.9.9.jar" />
<target name="testng-execution" depends="jarextraction">
    <testng testjar="${cashkaroJar}" xmlPathInJar="local/${xmlFile}" classpathref="classpath" useDefaultListeners="true">
        <sysproperty key="env.URL_key" value="CK_AUTO_DEV"></sysproperty> 
    </testng>
</target>
```